# how to disable a :hover affects rails twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that I want no hover affects on except for the hand/pointer icon.  Right now, by default, it changes the background color and the color.

I have a simple rails twitter bootstrap app with a link on my home#index page

```
<%= link_to(activities_path, class: "version muted pull-right") do %>
  <%= APP_VERSION %>
<% end %>
```

which produces the following html

```
<a href="/activities" class="version muted pull-right">
  dd6fe0e
</a>
```

I've tried to disable the hover affects by putting the following in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file.

```
a.version :hover { 
  background-color: $bodyBackground; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

This is what I have in my application.css.scss:

```
*= require_self
*= require font-awesome
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*= require jquery.Jcrop.min
*= require_tree .
```

It doesn't affect any changes-- like the selector is not matching, but if I remove the ":hover" part I do see the change on the link, so I'm not sure why the hover doesn't apply.  (When I had the contents of the link wrapped in a span, some changes were affected, but it displayed black above and below the link like there was some sizing difference, but I didn't notice anything in the web developer inspection.

Can someone please help me make this link show no hover effects?  And if I'm doing anything else wrong, I open to suggestions as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the space before `:hover` , like this:
`a.version:hover`